# Live Website on IIS throwing a SQL connection error

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis, windows-server-2012

My application is running fine on IIS server. However, when I try to query the database, the server responds with the error shown below:

[image]

I am assuming that it has something to do with how SQL Server is configured on the Windows Server 2012. I have tried to watch many videos and read many tutorials, with no luck of fixing it.

Trying to find the issue, I installed Visual Studio on the Windows Server and was successful in launching the application in "Start Without Debugging" mode. Doing so, the application was able to communicate with the server, using the same connection string.

This error message appears in the Windows Event Viewer:

> Cannot open database "TrimYard" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'

Comment: Why are you posting a screenshot of instructions about how to change to Development mode so you can see actual error details? Did you switch to Development mode and get the error details? If not, why not? If so, then please post them.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear about steps you can take to gather more information.

Comment: @Dai, yes I did. I downloaded Visual Studios on the server and ran the application in debug mode and it worked.

Comment: The error is suggesting swapping to a dev environment on the production server for the purposes of getting more information about the error. Its not saying run a separate dev version.

Comment: @DaleK Please tell me what information you need. I will be more than happy to provide it! In the mean time, I will try to find the windows event log. Haven't looked there yet. Thank you for the help!

Comment: @DaleK I listed more info. I have never looked in the event viewer before. Thank you for direction.

Comment: If you're using integration security to connect to the database, then the application needs to run as a user that has access to the database. Do you know how to change the user that an application pool runs as? Do you have a service account set up with the proper permissions?

Comment: Thanks, I posted the answer you all helped me find! Super thankful, I have been working on this project for months! They don't teach us this at our university.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, big thanks to @mason and @Dale K for the help! Dale mentioned it had something to do with the 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'. So, I search the text and found what that was. Then, I remembered, in a YouTube video a guy was trying to add users to the database with the correct permissions. Backtracking, I went in the Microsoft SSMS, opened Security tab, then the login tab, and right clicked on 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'.

[image]

Navigating the the User Mapping section, I checked the correct database and clicked OK. After that, I had to tell the sever that NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM was a db_owner. I did this by navigating through the tabs again.

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't run it as `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`. Create a separate domain account, have your app pool run as that, and give it permissions to your database.